# How to create sub-domain dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot, dns, subdomain

I have a website which is build using Spring boot, AngularJS and deployed in tomcat on openshift. I want to create subdomain on the fly, means as soon as user registered with us they will get customized url. I am able to do this by using GoDaddy control panel but it takes some time and I have to do manually every time new user register. So i want to know is there any way we can achieve this dynamically.

For Ex: When any new user registered with wordpress, instantly a subdomain is created for the user.

Comment: Basically you only need a wildcard DNS entry to forward all requests to *.yourdomain.com to your application, and then you can handle the requests there.

Comment: Can u tell me in detail , i bought domain from godaddy.com . So far what i did is i created a entry in Records For Ex : Name = * and value = my server ip. but when i trying abc.mydomain.com it says This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.

Comment: Anyone found solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, You would need to read user sub-domain somewhere in the servlet filter and also create security rules to prevent cross-sub-domain requests.